# C# code to increment by 1 an item in Application state

Tags: asp.net

How to write the C# code to increment by 1 an item in Application state named “total” in ASP.net?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can ask a certain error that you face while doing your work. Show some work that you have already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to modify any Application variables, you need to lock them before modifying it to ensure no inadvertent changes between parallel requests happen.

An example

```
 Application.Lock();
 var userCount = Convert.ToInt32(Application["OnlineUserCount"]);
 Application["OnlineUserCount"] = ++userCount;
 Application.UnLock();
```

[Application.Lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525184(v=vs.90).aspx) ensures that only one thread or request has access to the variables and other requests wait in queue.  You modify the values as per the need and [Application.Unlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524320(v=vs.90).aspx) to release your lock so other requests can work on Application variables.

Please note that there may be a performance hit, if you depend on this!!

> Note: A page does not need to lock the application object to edit the
>   application collection. If one page tries to edit the application
>   collection without locking and a second page also tries to edit the
>   collection, no error is sent by IIS and the Application object ends up
>   in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0):

Better use a

> static variable

and

> Interlocked.Increment

like this:

```
private static int total= 0;

public static void Increment()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref total);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Appreciated.. :)

Comment: @KDon just mark it as an answer if this is what you were looking for.